# VBA Save Range as Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to save a range as a separate workbook. Range I want to save is in Sheet (STF) and Range (B1 to J lastrow) My code is:

```
saveFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=address & " " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss"), fileFilter:="Excel Workbooks (*.xlsx),*.xlsx")
Worksheets("STF").Range("B1:J" & LR).SaveAs Filename:=saveFile
```

However, apparently, it is not that simple. It fails and I am not sure how to go around fixing this?

Help?

Comment: Copy the range you want to save to a new Workbook and then save that new Workbook.

Comment: So often the answer can be stripped down to: how would I do it manually? As Foxfire says, copy, paste, save, close. Exactly what you'd do if you were doing it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the worksheet to no location. This creates a new workbook (newly active) which contains the worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub extractRange()
    Dim saveFile As String, Address As String

    Address = "ABC"

    saveFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Address & " " & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss"), _
                                             fileFilter:="Excel Workbooks (*.xlsx),*.xlsx")
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("STF").Copy

    With ActiveWorkbook
        With .Worksheets("STF")
            .Columns("K:XFD").EntireColumn.Delete
            .Columns("A").EntireColumn.Delete
        End With
        .SaveAs Filename:=saveFile, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a workbook, copy / paste your required range to the new workbook, then save and close:

```
saveFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Address & " " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss"), fileFilter:="Excel Workbooks (*.xlsx),*.xlsx")
If Not saveFile = "False" Then
    With Workbooks.Add
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("STF").Range("B1:J" & LR).Copy .Sheets(1).Range("B1")
        .SaveAs saveFile
        .Close
    End With
End If
```